# OpenCV taking single camera frame while camera still running

Tags: python, image, opencv, camera

I wrote a script for an image processing. I need to take a frame from camera and then make some operations. I can do this but the time when script is initializing the camera is very long. Is there any solution that I will run my script and camera will be working all the time and for example when I will press a button it will save a frame?

This is my code for now:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)

while True:
    _, img = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Output', img)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('s'):
        print('DO IMAGE PROCESSING...')
    elif cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF==ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The problem is that when I am pressing "q" sometimes it doesn't stop. Can you give me an advice which loop or maybe which lib should I use for that?

Thanks!

Comment: if you have long running image processing then you may have to run it in separated thread/process because it blocks this code and it can't check keys. See [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: BTW: you could use  `waitKey(1)` before `if/else` - `value = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF` and later `if value == ord('s'): ... elif value == ord('q'): ...`